# Cadastro de Usuario em Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Estou começando com laravel faz umas 2 semanas e automaticamente está chovendo de dúvidas.

Tenho um formulário de Cadastro com o seguinte botão abaixo:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="cadastrar-usuario">
<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Cadastrar Usuário
</button>
```

Tenho um UsuarioController.php que faz a listagem dos Usuários, lembrando que não estou usando a tabela users do laravel mesmo, irei usar posteriormente.

Gostaria de chamar uma function do meu controller.

Meu Controller está assim:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class UsuarioController extends Controller {

    public function lista(){
        $usuarios = DB::select("select * from usuarios");

        return view('usuarios.listagem')->with('usuarios', $usuarios);
    }

}

?>
```

Como eu poderia chamar ele usando ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você precisa criar uma rota no arquivo arquivo de rotas em `app/Http/routes.php`, acrescente:

```
Route::get('listausuarios', 'UsuarioController@lista');
```

No Javascript da sua View, considerando que você está usando JQuery, adicione o evento click ao botão:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $("#cadastrar-usuario").on('click', function() {

        jQuery.get("listausuarios", function(data){
            //Tratamendo dos dados recebidos em formado json
        });
});
```

Vi que você retorna uma `view`, ao invés de um `JSON` no seu Controller. Teria que mudar isso também.
Mas caso você queira apenas pegar o click do botão e mudar de rota, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira no Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $("#cadastrar-usuario").on('click', function() {
        window.location.href = 'listausuarios';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Só para complementar a resposta anterior! 
Você poderá utilizar a retorno do método da seguinte forma.
Criando um modelo da tabela dos usuários, usando o recurso do Eloquent e depois chamando o mesmo no seu Controlador:

```
return response()->json(Usuarios::all());
```

Ou retornando sua variável `$usuarios` dessa forma:

```
return response()->json(['usuarios' => $usuarios]);
```

Qualquer uma dessas formas lhe retornará um objeto JSON.

Comment: Não entende se é uma pergunta ou uma resposta?

Comment: Só para complementar a publicação da primeira resposta, de como ele pode efetuar o retorno em JSON

Comment: Quando for complementar você pode **Editar** sua resposta ou por os Complementos nos Comentários... Isso deixar sua pergunta/Resposta mais limpa e legível.